# GNU Parallel jobs in background

Tags: gnu-parallel

I have questions when using gnu parallel to run my jobs. Despite setting `--results` argument and end my command with an "&", bash still show whatever outputs from my command to the screen. Here is a general structure of my codes (assuming the program I run is called "command", and filenames.txt store line-by-line all the input files):

```
parallel -a filenames.txt -j 6 --results logs/ --joblog joblog command --input {} --output {}.out &
```

In addition, I wonder if using `disown` in this situation would cause any problems. In one of my run, it is weird that the `joblog` file appears to be interrupted and stop updating despite more jobs had been run. From the output files (stderr, set by `--results`), most of the jobs that were not recorded by `joblog` file were actually completed, with some incomplete stderr. I wasn't sure if those jobs with incomplete stderr completed successfully or not because the output files (set by `--output`) looks normal in file size. I checked the timestamp of the `joblog` file, the last update time may have been when I used `disown` (although I am not certain).

In general, from the manual and tutorial of GNU Parallel, I am not sure the compatibility of running parallel in background.

Thanks!

J

Comment: Is there a chance that your command use some unusual output stream? Not stdout nor stderr which GNU Parallel consumes.

Comment: @lojza Not I know of, however, I am not sure for certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--results` also prints a copy to stdout/stderr. This is likely to change in the future (see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/parallel/2020-12/msg00003.html).

Right now you simply redirect the output to /dev/null.

I have long ago stopped using `disown`. Instead I log in to the remote server, start `tmux`, and run jobs in `tmux`. `disown` should not affect GNU Parallel, though, so I cannot explain the weird situation you see with `--joblog`.

Comment: Thanks! This is good to know. I would vote "Change it - I would prefer the new behaviour".

Comment: Regarding the interrupted log file, I wonder if it is because I closed the terminal after typed disown, because according to answers here [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and), "the program will fail as soon as it tries to read from standard input or write to standard output." But this won't explain why only 4 of 49 jobs did not finish. The reason I had to close the terminal is because I am ssh to a remote server and the job takes a long time to complete.